# Switch and Select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select, switch-statement

I'm new in JavaScript.. Here is my question.. I have drop down list :

```
<div class="spanNav-row" id="spanNav-row">
  <select name="timeDropList">

    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="60" selected>60</option>
    <option value="Vac">Vacation</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

and I have a switch :

```
switch () {

  case 6:
    break;
  case 10:
    break;
  case 15:
    break;
  case 30:
    break;
  case 60:
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

How do you transfer values of drop down list to the switch?

Comment: Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/PCGjU/ You'll need to have either Chrome Console or Firefox Firebug console open to see output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard JS:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("timeDropList");
var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

switch (selectedValue) {}
```

jQuery (in case you're interested):

```
switch($('#timeDropList option:selected').val()) {}
```

**NOTE:** To reference the drop down by getElementById(), timeDropList will also have to be the ID, not just the name:

```
<select id="timeDropList" name="timeDropList">
```

Comment: okey.. Can You please explain why you used getElementsById("spanNav-row") but not "timeDropList" ?

Comment: This throws an error because the `options` HTMLCollection doesn't exist on an HTMLDivElement. I'd suggest attaching an `id` attribute to the select, and then doing a switch against its value.

Comment: @Sergio, apologies, updated. I blame it on the tiny netbook screen. I copied and pasted the wrong id...

Comment: @James Hill - Don't worry, everyone else got it wrong too. :) The only thing I would note is that it's a `name` value and not an `id` value...

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I just updated that in my post before I saw your comment. Seriously, the 9" screen is killing me :)

Comment: @James - Yeah, I just noticed you had edited it as well. It would be nice if SO autoloaded edits and comments.

Comment: @James - I also noticed the problems when I was putting together a http://jsfiddle.net demo. You might consider doing those of your answers in the future if you're not already (since they catch silly errors like that). :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I usually do, for that reason. To be honest, I'm on vacation and the wife doesn't really appreciate seeing me SO for fun and recreation :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var swi_var = document.getElementById('spanNav-row').value;
```

`swi_var` can go in the switch

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it would be piece a cake:

```
var selectedValue = $('#spanNav-row').val();
switch (selectedValue) {
    // Your switch body here.
}
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with JavaScript, without the jQuery bloat: `document.getElementById("id_of_select").value;`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree @Matt. But the real application goes beyond that. So why not incorporating jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is great, but in this case the OP didn't mention it and there's a really straightforward answer that doesn't need it...